# In Sharepoint 2010 is it possible to click a list item and have that bring up a form again to edit this item?

Tags: list, list-view

I have a pretty typical Sharepoint List that looks like below:
[image]

Is there way I can set this view up so that I can click somewhere on one of the records (i.e. Jonathan Morgan) and this will pull up a form with all the existing information already entered in but where I can edit all of the information in this row?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to open Edit form of the item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the available columns that you can add to the view is titled "Edit", and it usually works best to place this column first in the view. It will display as a small icon that, when clicked, will bring up the edit form for the record.

Answer (score 2):

You have three options to open up an edit form from the list.

1. Edit
2. Title

Edit opens the edit from, while title opens the view form, from which you can navigate to edit from also. You can enable these columns by modifying the view.

[image]

Other way is to create a calculated column and adding a link to the form if you know the URL like:

```
="<a href='"&%URL_Field_Name%&"'> "&[%field_name%]&"</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to click anywhere then you'll have to create some custom javascript on your list view page that will add an "onclick" event handler to every "tr" that will open the edit page for that item. It would work but then you end up with duplicate onclick events if the row has any links in it.